# how to access the nested json element?

Tags: javascript, json

```
contact1 : {name: "Kesh", relation: "Mother", number: "9819269972"}
```

this is particular data is part of a bigger json data. I am accessing it via JSONArrayName.contact1. How do i access name, relation and number now?

```
var obj, dbParam, xmlhttp, myObj, x, txt = "";  
obj = { "table":"Successful", "limit":20 };
dbParam = JSON.stringify(obj); 
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
    myObj = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
    console.log(myObj);
    //console.log(myObj[0]);
    document.getElementById("userId").innerHTML = myObj.id;
    document.getElementById("DOB").innerHTML = myObj.dob;
    document.getElementById("bloodGroup").innerHTML = myObj.bloodGroup;
    document.getElementById("aadhar").innerHTML = myObj.aadharCard;
    document.getElementById("allergies").innerHTML = myObj.allergies;
    document.getElementById("insurances").innerHTML = 
    myObj.insuranceDetails;
    var contact1 = myObj.contact1;
    console.log(contact1);
```

}

console output:
myobj:

{id: "123456", insuranceDetails: null, allergies: null, bloodGroup: "A", gender: "Female", contact1: {name: "Kesh", relation: "Mother", number: "9819269972"}, contact2: {name: "Kesh", relation: "Mother", number: "9819269972"}}

contact1:

{name: "Kesh", relation: "Mother", number: "9819269972"}

Comment: what does the console print?

Comment: Are you sure that `xmlhttp.responseText` variable is correct JSON?

Comment: yeah, that is surely correct

Answer (score 2):

Use [Dot-Notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors) to access the value corresponding to keys in the object.

```js
var JSONArrayName = {contact1 : {name: "Kesh", relation: "Mother", number: "9819269972"}};

console.log(JSONArrayName.contact1.name);
console.log(JSONArrayName.contact1.relation);
```

Comment: i have editted the above code. Here, if i do myObj.contact1.name i get "undefined" as my console output

Answer (score 0):

You can access them by using `dot notation` like

```
var data = { contact1 : {name: "Kesh", relation: "Mother", number: "9819269972"} } 
console.log(data.contact1.name);
console.log(data.contact1.relation);
console.log(data.contact1.number);
```

Comment: i have editted the above code. Here, if i do myObj.contact1.name i get "undefined" as my console output

Answer (score 0):

can access the data in such a way:

myObj.contact[0].name

Answer (score 0):

In my console it work fine, make sure that you have a non empty variable `myObj`
[image: Console]